# Magento mageworx not saving well

Tags: php, magento

I have in my shop custom option with the extentension mageworx.

When a edit a option it not good saving the changes.

Magento 1.8.0.

Is it possible that a make checkbox in each field and that ik can choose which field a wil override and which field not? How do i that?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731798/magento-custom-option-checkbox-ignore-saving-field

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are using the latest version of the APO extension. If it still doesn't work, please contact our Support Dept. (support.mageworx.com).
If you would like to have a check-box for every option's attribute to determine what should be updated, we can customize the extension for you.

Let us know if you have any questions.

Happy New Year.